# Show that weakly convergence of probability measures on countable space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{X})$ be a metric space where assume that $X$ is countable and discrete. Show that probability measures $P_n$ converges to $P$ weakly (i.e., for all bounded continuous functions on $X$, one has $\int f dP_i\to \int f dP$) if and only if $P_n(\{x\})\to P(\{x\})$ as $n\to \infty$.

---

For one direction, assume that $P_n$ converges to $P$ weakly. We choose $f(x)=I[\{x\}]$. Then
$$
\int f dP_n=\int I[\{x\}] dP_n=P_n(\{x\})\to \int fdP=P(\{x\})
$$

But how to claim that $I[\{x\}]$ is continuous? (It is bounded by 1).

On the other hand, assume that $P_n(\{x\})\to P(\{x\})$ as $n\to \infty$. Assume that $|f|\le C$ for some $C>0$. Let $X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$. Then
$$
|\int f dP_n- \int f dP|=|\sum_if(x_i)P_n(x_i)-\sum_if(x_i)P(x_i)|\le C\sum_{x_i}|P_n(x_i)-P(x_i)|
$$

Then as $n\to \infty$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^\infty|P_n(x_i)-P(x_i)|=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}|P_n(x_i)-P(x_i)|=0
$$

(How to verify it?)

---

We use the fact that every open $G$ set is the countable union of finite sets. Actually, every set. If $G = \{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ we set $G_k= \cup^k_{i=1}\{x_i\}$ and $G_k \uparrow G$ then $\lim_kP(G_k) \to P(G)$. So for every $\epsilon>0$ exists $G_k$ such that $P(G-G_k)<\epsilon$ and
$$P(G) < \epsilon + P(G_k) = \epsilon + \liminf_n P_n(G_k) \leq \epsilon + \liminf P_n(G).$$
Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary we can conclude with Portmateu theorem.

Comment: For the first part, $I(\{x\})$ is continuous because every function on a discrete space is continuous. The last equality does not hold -- in fact, it is possible that the LHS is $\infty$ for every $n$. Try to see why that is -- it may help you work out what it is you need to do.

Comment: Last part is the well known Scheffe's Lemma (for counting measure). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma

Comment: @Hermi I was giving a hint, not answering the question for you. And yes, you can do $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ if you wish to prove that $I$ is continuous. It is better to try first before asking.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum (P(x_i)-P_n(x_i))^{+} \to 0$ by dominated Convergence Theorem since $0 \le (P(x_i)-P_n(x_i))^{+} \leq P(x_i)$ and $\sum P(x_i) <\infty$. Also, $\sum (P(x_i)-P_n(x_i)) =1-1=0$. Since $x^{-}=x^{+}-x$ we get $\sum (P(x_i)-P_n(x_i))^{-} \to 0$. Finally, $|x|=x^{+}+x^{-}$ so $\sum |P(x_i)-P_n(x_i)| \to 0$.

Comment: Can we use Portmanteau-Theorem? Every open $G$ set is the countable union of finite sets?

Comment: Also, is my first part proof ok? Just choose indicator function?

Comment: Yes, the first part is fine because any function is continuous on a discrete space. @Hermi

Comment: Can you please take a look at my update approach? Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use Portmanteau's Theorem, then your argument is fine. But I think DCT is more elementary. @Hermi